# Independent sets of subsets

Tags: co.combinatorics

The question is simply: let $|S| = n,$ how big can a subset $I$ of $2^S$ be such that for any $A, B \in I,$ $A\not\subset B$ (so, this is an independent set in the graph whose vertices are subsets, and edges correspond to inclusion in some direction). It is clear that $|I| \geq \binom{n} {\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor},$ but is that sharp?

**Update** As Gerhard points out, the answer is YES. Now a followup: what about a family which has no $k$-element chain $A\subset B \subset \dotsc \subset C?$

Comment: Sperner sets.  Gerhard "Yes, Antichains Are That Big" Paseman, 2017.10.27.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Truly you are wise in the ways of science!

Comment: There is a very nice recent survey of progress on these kinds of problems, by Griggs and Li, at https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-24298-9_14. Thm 1.2 covers your updated question.

Comment: Not so sure about the follow up.  I would guess the union of k-1 antichains, which gives a naive upper bound of (k-1) times the middle binomial coefficient.  Gerhard "Slight Improvements Available Upon Request" Paseman, 2017.10.27.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Yes, I had surmised the naive bound, but wonder if it is sharp. I will try to find D. Galvin's reference...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To address the updated question, a family of subsets of $[n]$ is called *$k$-Sperner* if it does not contain a chain of length $k+1$.  By taking all sets whose size lies in the middle $k$ values of $[n]$, there exist $k$-Sperner families who size is the sum of the $k$ middle bịnomial coefficients. Erdős proved that this bound is tight in this [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183507531)  (see Theorem 5).  The extremal example is also essentially unique (for parity reasons there may be two intervals of middle $k$ values).

Comment: It seems you've accidentally posted two answers ...

Comment: Yes, I was bumbling on my phone.  I deleted the other answer, thanks.

Comment: Also, the OP should have a look at the LYM inequality. It implies his original question (Sperner's Theorem) and it's generalisation to chains of length k (first proved by Erdős).